# How to fix "git-sh-setup: file not found" in windows?

Tags: windows, git

I was using Git and it was working fine but after a restart, it shows the following error:

> **git-sh-setup: file not found**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details about this error?

Comment: I've the same problem since I've installed Git v2.17.1.2 for Windows and I've found a workaround. You can try to add `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core` in the `PATH` env variable. It works for me.

Answer (score 69):

I've run into this issue with the latest *Git on Windows* (v2.17.1.windows.2) and solved it both for `cmd` and PowerShell by adding two directories to `PATH`:

- `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`
- `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`

[image]

From elevated powershell you could set it using:

```
$env:Path += ";c:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $env:Path
```

Comment: yeah, that's it (+1), but in my case got this to work after a reboot.

Answer (score 5):

If the above comment will not help try to open the powershell, or whatever you are using for terminal in administrator mode. In my case it helped.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue in the `powershell`, I just switched to `git bash` and ran the `npm i` then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

weird solution, in my project package.json->scripts section this command was written
`"install:submodules": "git submodule update --init --recursive",`

when I was using command `npm run install:submodules` I was facing this error

but when I directly used the command `git submodule update --init --recursive` it ran successfully.