# npm script is unable to run git submodule in Windows

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I'm running Windows, and when I run `git submodule` from git bash or cmd or PowerShell, it works as expected and exits without error. But when I create an npm script in my `package.json` like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "sth": "git submodule"
}
```

And try to run it like `npm run sth`, it gives me this error:

```
> test-project@0.1.0 sth D:\...\test-project
> git submodule

D:/Program_Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-submodule: line 22: .: git-sh-setup: file not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-project@0.1.0 sth: `git submodule`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-project@0.1.0 sth script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\.....
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like your PATH is probably wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49256190/how-to-fix-git-sh-setup-file-not-found-in-windows/50833818

Comment: git is supposed to add `git-core` to the PATH itself. And it does it when it's not run by npm. The thing is that when npm runs git, then `git-core` path is not added to the PATH.